# GCloud: Copying Files from Local Machine into a Docker Container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a straightforward way to copy files from a local machine into a docker container within a VM instance on Google Compute Engine?

I know `gcloud compute ssh --container=XX` is an easy way to execute commands on a container, but there's no analogous `gcloud compute scp --container=XX`. Note: I created this VM and docker container with the command `gcloud alpha compute instances create-from-container ...`

Note, better than just being able to transfer files, it would be nice to have an `rsync` type functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, looks like it's not available without some setup on your part (and it's not in beta): creating a volume map notwithstanding, you could do it by running sshd inside the container listening on it's own port mapped to the host:

- gcloud compute firewall-rules create CONTAINER-XX-SSH-RULE --allow
  tcp:2022 --target-tags=XX-HOST
- gcloud compute scp --port 2022 --recurse stuff/ user@XX-HOSTNAME:

  or
- scp -r -P 2022 stuff/ user@xx-host-ip:

Answer (score 1):

I generally use an approach where I use object storage in-between local machines and a cloud VMs.  On AWS I use `s3 sync`, on Google you can use `gsutil rsync`

First the data on a 'local' development machine gets pushed into object storage when I'm ready to deploy it.

- (The data in question is a snapshot of a git repository + some binary
  files).
- (Sometimes the development machine in question is a laptop, sometimes
  my desktop, sometimes a cloud IDE.  They all run git).

Then the VM pulls content from object storage using `s3 sync`.  I think you can do the same with `gsutil` to pull data from Google object storage into a Google container.  (In fact it seems you can even rsync between clouds using gsutil).

This is my shoestring dev-ops environment.  It's a little bit more work, but using object storage as a middleman for syncing snapshots of data between machines provides a bit of flexibility, a reproducible environment and peace of mind.